# PHP ldap_connect always returns false

Tags: php, ldap

We currently have a class like below

```
class LDAP {
        private static $_singleton ;
        public static function getInstance()
        {
                if(is_null(self::$_singleton)) {
                        self::$_singleton =  ldap_connect("ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:389");
                        if(self::$_singleton){
                                ldap_set_option(self::$_singleton, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, LDAP_VERSION);
                                $b = ldap_bind(LDAP::getInstance(), LDAP_BINDDN, LDAP_BINDPW) ;
                        }
                }

                return self::$_singleton ;
        }
}
```

But we always get "false" while trying to "connect" (ldap_connect).

My colleagues don't have any problems when they try to authenticate on their localhost. Only on my localhost we have problems (with the same configuration and same sources).
We tried to reinstall php (8.0.19) and also try with other 8.0.x version but always the same issue.
We also tried to copy/past from other host, but always the same issue.

Also try to compare apache\bin files.

Any idea why ldap_connect method always returns false ?

Comment: ldap_connect() doesn't actually connect. _"It's a syntactic check of the provided parameter but the server(s) will not be contacted! If the syntactic check fails it returns false."_ You should also be getting a warning with a more descriptive error message when this happens.

Comment: Yes I have a warning when the ldap_connect is called : Warning: ldap_connect(): Could not create session handle... But that's not really helpful. The question is, why the syntactic check fails

Comment: Start from beginning: have you checked you have enabled `ldap extension` in php.ini?

Comment: Yes, the "extension=ldap" doesn't have the ";"

Comment: What is the output of `ldap_bind()`?

Comment: `ldap_connect()` returns false, so it doesn't enter in the "if" to call the `ldap_bind()`

Comment: What is the actual value you're passing to ldap_connect? If it's a string built from a variable, and the variable is empty, that will possibly produce the error you're getting.

Comment: I tried with multiple ways. Using string built from a string or directly a string, always had the same issue

Comment: We solved the issue with a colleague... I used his php folder and it works ! I tried to use my previous php folder and it's still working :-( We didn't change anything else but now it's working... We don't really understand why, but it works fine now